# Sharing references to the same object as multiple ivars among several classes

Tags: objective-c

The following is not the best organization of shared data, but I still want to know why it isn't working..

`SharedClass` in this example is not a singleton, just a regular object getting passed around.

Class A has ivar:

`@property (nonatomic, retain) SharedClass*sharedClass;`

Classes B and C both have this:

`@property (nonatomic,assign) SharedClass*sharedClass;`

(the "assign" in this case could be "retain", I don't think that matters for this question)

Class A initializes the ivar in its `init`:

`self.sharedClass=[[SharedClass new] autorelease]; // autorelease since it is retained`

Class B does *not* handle the ivar in its init. Instead, Class B is instantianted within Class A's init, and pass a reference after, like this:

In Class A

`self.classB=[[ClassB new] autorelease];
self.classB.sharedClass=self.sharedClass; // passing a reference to same object; this is working as expected`

Here's what I don't understand. Class C is instantiated in Class B's `init` and also passed a reference, but since this is occurring before Class B gets its object from Class A, it is temporarily null, which I'd expect:

Class B:

`self.classC=[[ClassC new] autorelease];
self.classC.sharedClass=self.sharedClass; //self.sharedClass is currently nil, thus so is self.classC.sharedClass`

After Class B is instantiated in Class A (and thus Class C also gets instantiated inside Class B) and Class A assigns `sharedClass` to Class B, shouldn't this ripple through so that the `sharedClass` object is now also available in Class C? Just because it was nil, it was still pointing at a space that is now no longer nil, right?

However I'm finding that Class C can only reference the sharedClass if a further step is handled in Class A:

`self.classB=[[ClassB new] autorelease];
self.classB.sharedClass=self.sharedClass;
self.classB.classC.sharedClass=self.sharedClass;//why is this necessary?`

Comment: Is `SharedClass` a singleton? (I assume it's not)

Comment: No it is not. just a regular object being passed around (again, not the smartest way to organize an app but I expect it should work anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `self.sharedClass` is `nil` at your assignment

```
self.classC.sharedClass = self.sharedClass;
```

then `self.classC.sharedClass` is also `nil`, and assigning something to `self.sharedClass` later does not change that.

> Just because it was nil, it was still pointing at a space that is now
>   no longer nil, right?

That is wrong, `nil` is a "null object" and does not point anywhere.